# javascript is not loading on ssl

Tags: javascript, php, ssl, whmcs

I've a WHMCS installed on my host. I've just added a simple code to rotate our certificates logo and it's working fine in the main page (and also Non-SSL pages), take a loot please (down in right column of the page):

http://www.irpowerweb.com/

but in SSL pages it's not working:

https://www.irpowerweb.com/register.php

eth is same in both paths and the only difference is about SSL (HTTPS).

I find out the problem is not related to the insecure content on my page ('enamad.ir/trustseal/symbol.aspx') because I removed it but problem exists.

any helps are appreciated.

Comment: The Javascript console says: **[blocked] The page at 'https://www.irpowerweb.com/register.php' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://enamad.ir/trustseal/symbol.aspx': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.**

Comment: Yeah, I read it, but I thought it's not related to this issue, let me try.

Comment: I've tried your solution but unfortunetally this iFrame source is external and it's not supporting SSL and also I can not remove it because it's important. Is there anyway to solve this problem and have both iFrame and Script working together?

Comment: I've just removed the iFrame (insecure content) but problem exists, so it's not related to the insecure content. Waiting for your help :)